# MessageBox.YesNo in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, messagebox

I would like to make ASP.NET page react to user action same way as it is possible in WinForms with `MessageBox.YesNo`.

```
Button has been pressed
do some action
set condition true or false

if(condition) {
    Display messagebox to user catch its return value
}
if(return value true) { 
    do something
}
else {
    do something else
}
```

Comment: You can't do anything UI-related from the *server*. This can only be done on the browser using Javascript

Comment: For something like that you'd have to use Javascript as ASP.net doesn't provide such a feature.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Server-Side-Code-Behind-Yes-No-Confirmation-Message-Box-in-ASPNet.aspx

Comment: @Agramer no server-side code provides such features. That's just how the web is

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Doesn't *always* need JS, but it's likely much easier.

Comment: use `window.confirm()` on client side to detect user choise

Comment: Of course this is possible in the code-behind. Almost every HTML-Element can be set to runat-server and shown/hidden with visible in the code-behind. Just prepare both in the ascx and show them accordingly.

Comment: I am sorry but I do not understand. I need to raise a "messagebox" automatically from code not to press any buttons which will cause this box appear.

Answer (score -1):

use window.confirm()

```
if(confirm("Are you sure?")){
   //Executes code if pressed yes
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp

Comment: I do not understand how can I react to something like this in my code behind page.

Comment: @Bendom You can execute a Get or Post request after the confirmation...